# How do you correctly and programmatically recycle an app pool on an IIS server

Tags: asp.net, iis, recycle

This is what I am currently doing

```
public static string RecycleSite(string siteName)
{
    try
    {
        using (ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            SiteCollection sites = iisManager.Sites;
            foreach (Site site in sites)
            {
                if (site.Name == siteName)
                {
                    ObjectState os = iisManager.ApplicationPools[site.Applications["/"].ApplicationPoolName].Recycle();
                    return "Recycle Successful";
                }
            }
        }
        return "Recycle Unsuccessful";
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return "Recycle Unsuccessful: " + ex;
    }
```

I have viewed multiple other threads, but none seem to have the answer I am look for. I want to use the Server Manager class to recycle a specific IIS site. This current solution does a "recycle" but it also kills any active connections that are still present. The IIS manager is set up so I can begin a new instance while there are persisting connections on the current instance until those connections have closed on their own.

Is my solution correct or do I need to go about recycling in a more direct way? This is part of a console application that is set to run as an admin so that my other service that is calling is can sit under a user account (security reasons). Using IIS 8.5 on Server 2012 R2.